# How to display an array ,of fetched data from database, to dropdown list in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

Hi everyone I am facing problem assigning array(fetched from database) to dropdown list. Here is the Code

Controller Code

```
$skill_rows = $this->Skill->find("all");
$this->set(compact("skill_rows"));
```

CTP Code

```
$skills = $skill_rows;
echo $this->Form->select("Seeker.skills",$skills,array("empty"=>"Select"));
```

Database

```
id   skill
1    PHP
2    CakePHP
```

I wish to display only skill column in drop down list but it is displaying complete table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$this->Skill->find("list");` to return an array of primary key-display field values that can be used in your dropdown. You might need to specify `skill` as the `displayField` for this to work correctly.

**CakePHP 2**

In CakePHP 2 the `displayField` is an attribute of the model:-

```
class Skill extends AppModel {

    public $displayField = 'skill';

}
```

Alternatively you can define the columns you want to be returned in the list when you perform your `find()`:-

```
$this->Skill->find('all', [
    'fields' => [
        'Skill.id',
        'Skill.skill'
    ]
]);
```

**CakePHP 3**

In CakePHP 3 you can define the `displayField` in the model:-

```
class SkillsTable extends Table
{

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->displayField('skill');
    }
}
```

If you want to do this on the `find()` query in CakePHP 3 you need to define the `keyField` and `valueField`:-

```
$this->Skill->find('list', [
    'keyField' => 'id',
    'valueField' => 'skill'
]);
```