# Option value in drop down list

Tags: cakephp

I have trouble in creating cakephp option value.

My code in add.ctp

```
<h1>New Book</h1>
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Book',array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'));
echo $this->Form->input('title');
echo $this->Form->input('author');
echo $this->Form->input('summary',array('rows' => '3'));
echo $this->Form->input('category',array('type'=>'select','options'=>$category));
echo $this->Form->input('price');
echo $this->Form->input('image',array('type'=>'file'));
echo $this->Form->end('Save');
?>
```

And controller add function

```
public function add(){
    $this->loadModel('Category');
    $category =$this->Category->find('all', array('fields'=>'name'));
    debug($category);
    $this->set('category',$category);
    if($this->request->is('post')){

    $this->Book->create();
    $filePath="./img/images/".$this->request->data['Book']['image']['name'];
    $filename=$this->request->data['Book']['image']['tmp_name'];
    if(move_uploaded_file($filename, $filePath)){
        $this->request->data['Book']['cover']=$this->request->data['Book']['image']['name'];
    }
    if ($this->Book->save($this->request->data)) {
        $this->Flash->success(__('Your book has been saved.'));
    }
    return $this->redirect(array('controller' =>'Books','action' => 'index'));
    }
}
```

I only want my list box in my categories name  can't do with foreach in my form. Why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42291925/how-to-display-an-array-of-fetched-data-from-database-to-dropdown-list-in-cake/42292168#42292168

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

`$category =$this->Category->find('all', array('fields'=>'name'));`

To

`$category =$this->Category->find('list');`